# RxSwift — background task without freezing UI

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, rx-swift

I would like to do some heavy lifting in the background thread of my iOS app and NOT freeze the UI while it is being performed. What I try is:

```
self.someDisposable = heavyLiftingFuncReturningObservable()
            .subscribeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe(
                onNext: { [weak self] image in
                    // update UI
                },
                onError: { ... }
            )
```

Why does the above not work as expected and how to make it work?

Comment: I think making that Observable `lazy` could help. It could help, that it will be actually called when needed (from `.background` queue) and not when defined.

Comment: Unfortunately not — the UI freezes anyway.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the problem lies in your implementation of *.heavyLiftingFuncReturningObservable()*, namely in the fact that apparently it starts working on current thread instead of waiting until being subscribed to and running on background scheduler. Solution for that is to use *.deferred()* inside of *.heavyLiftingFuncReturningObservable()* function.

See http://adamborek.com/top-7-rxswift-mistakes/

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
self.someDisposable = Observable.just(0) // dummy
    .observeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
    .flatMap { [unowned self] _ in
        heavyLiftingFuncReturningObservable()
    }
    .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
    .subscribe(
        onNext: { [weak self] image in
            // update UI
        },
        onError: { ... }
    )
```

Comment: I am unsure about the subscribeOn
This applies only once, but shouldn't it be observeOn here to force the switch after the initial first observeOn(... .background)?

Comment: @altagir found answer on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65118983/6734130

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this... use the `Observable.deferred { }` method

Put the heavy task inside the block and it will run on subscription.

If the work has a single response, use a `Single` observable type.
If the work only has to complete, use a `Completable` observable type

Use the `observeOn` / `subscribleOn` operators to control the thread doing the work.

Best of all, don't use RX for this use case.